# Showing orders of user in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to give ability on user to see his orders. How can I query the database.. I'm trying something like this but I got empty page.. I mean nothing from database. May be my query ins't correct.

This is my controller

```
public function viewOrders() {
    $user_order = self::$user->user_id;
    $orders = Order::where('user_id', '=', $user_order);
    return View::make('site.users.orders', [
        'orders' => $orders
    ]);
}
```

Am I getting correctly user_id here? I'm not sure...

Update: I have this in my User model

```
public function orders() {
    return $this->hasMany('Order', 'user_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Comment: You can get the user id with `Auth::id()`. Also, you should add a relationship to your user of "hasMany Order" to get the orders associated to the user with `$user->orders`

Comment: I have updated my question with what I have in my `User` model

Comment: I put also `$user_order = Auth::id();` and still doesn't show any results

Comment: For debugging you can use the helper function [dd](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#miscellaneous). Make sure `Auth::id()` is getting you the authenticated user's id. If that is correct check what is the content of the variable `$orders`. If they have the correct contents then check how is your view trying to display that data.

Comment: View works for sure because I can load all content of table. Just can't display when I try to display only for this user_id

Comment: Can you show your `route` and button? Did you get user_id on button? or token?

Comment: My button `<a href="{{ URL::to('/users/orders') }}?_token={{ csrf_token() }}">Orders</a>` and my route `Route::get('/users/orders', ['uses' => 'UsersController@viewOrders', 'before' => 'auth|csrf']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so based on your route+button+model do it like this

```
$orders = self::$user->orders()->orderBy('order_id', 'asc')->get();
return View::make('site.users.orders', [
    'orders' => $orders
]);
```

this should work.. You can remove orderBy clause if you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have [Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#authenticating-users) set properly you can do the following.

```
public function viewOrders(){
    $user = Auth::user();
    return view('site.users.orders',[
        'orders' => $user->orders
    ]);
}
```

When you use the relationship without using the calling parentheses you get a collection of models which are queried if they're not already loaded. This is called lazy loading, if you want to load a relationship before accessing it you can use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading). In this case, it is not necessary though.

Comment: `'Trying to get property of non-object'` on here `'orders' => $user->orders`

Comment: I have this after login `Session::put('user', ['user_id' => $user->user_id]); return Redirect::to('/');`

Comment: I have tried also like this: `$orders = DB::table('orders')->where('user_id', '=', $user_order)->get();` but i got `Call to undefined method stdClass::getOrderData()` What this mean?