# How to display orders in a user account, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to display orders of a buyer and product details like name, price,total etc. After a buyer logged in should be able to see his order history and the product he ordered . So far when I dd($orders) I get order details but not product details,this is what I get->(https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7j6T.jpg). So how do I get product details too.

Here is my models and functions

Buyer Function

```
 public function myOrders()
 { 
 $orders = auth()->user()->allOrderFromBuyers()->with('orders')->get();
dd($orders);
return view('myOrders')->with(compact('orders'));

  }
```

User.php

```
   public function products()
  {
  return $this->hasMany(Products_model::class);
  }

   public function orders()
  {
   return $this->hasMany(Order::class, Products_model::class, 'buyer_id', 'seller_id', 'product_id');
   }

   public function allOrderFromBuyers()
   {
    return $this->hasMany(OrderProduct::class, 'buyer_id');
    }
```

Oder.php

```
   public function user()
   {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
   }

   public function products()
   {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Products_model::class, 'order_product');//gggg
   }

 public function orders(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\OrderProduct', 'order_id');
 }
```

Products_model.php

```
  protected $fillable= ['seller_id','pro_name','pro_price','pro_info','image','stock','category_id'];

 public function orders() 
 {
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order', 'order_product');
 }
```

OrderProduct.php

```
  public function products()
  {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Products_model');
  }

public function buyer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'buyer_id');
}

public function orders()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
 }
```

I have tried my best but am stuck, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing orders of user in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37874771/showing-orders-of-user-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

The way you have defined your relationships is very confusing but this is what I picked up :
 **You did this:**

```
 $orders = auth()->user()->allOrderFromBuyers()->with('orders')->get()
```

You are trying to get all orders from Buyers when your relationships are not properly defined ..

First let's clean your relations, in your Order.php

```
 public function orders(){
 return $this->hasMany('App\OrderProduct', 'order_id');
```

}

**shouldbe:**

```
 public function orderDetails(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\OrderProduct', 'order_id');
 }
```

**Then you can do:**

```
auth()->user()->orders()->with('orderDetails')->get()
```

Or you can lody lazy this as:

```
auth()->user()->orders()->load('orderDetails');
```

I have also noted an error in your user Model, please fix it, you can't have 2 Models in one relation never works .

```
public function orders()
  {
   return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
   }
```

Let me know how it goes .

Comment: I get this `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::load()"`  or if I use the first method I get `1054 Unknown column 'orders.App\Products_model' in 'where clause'` @Peace

Comment: Can you dd this (auth()->user()->orders());

Comment: I get the same error `Unknown column 'orders.App\Products_model'`

Comment: You need to seperate these 2  in your user class::
```
public function orders()
  {
   return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
   }
```

Comment: How do I separate?@Peace

Comment: In your User Model ...

 public function orders()
  {
   return $this->hasMany(Order::class, Products_model::class, 'buyer_id', 'seller_id', 'product_id');
   }

You to have public function orders() {} and public function products() {}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195198/discussion-between-peace-ngara-and-joh).